# Upgrading Mongodb from 3.2.6 to 4.2. Which is the better way to do it?

Tags: mongodb, upgrade

What is the best way to upgrade MongoDB?

Say I have 3.2.6 and I want to upgrade to 4.2

Can I just use mongodump and mongorestore? Or are there any intricacies to it?

Answer (score 1):

I would follow one of these documents that are published by MongoDB.

- [Upgrade a Replica Set to 4.2](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.2-upgrade-replica-set/)
- [Upgrade a Standalone to 4.2](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.2-upgrade-standalone/)

Comment: Thanks. That's way I am doing it. But it's so much hassle, so I was wondering why not just dump and restore? Do you see any problem in that?